# Syntax error at line 1 : `(' is not expected

Tags: shell, unix, sqlplus, ksh, quoting

As I'm new to Unix, can someone help why I get this error?

```
Error: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 1 : `(' is not expected
```

Unix server used: AIX servname 1 6 00F635064C00

Script used (to send email alert if day before yesterday source files didn't arrive):

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

count=$(sqlplus $PROD_DB @select count(*) from file_audit where (file_name like '%abc%' or file_name like '%dce%') and substr(file_name,17,8)=to_char(to_date(sysdate-2,'DD/MM/YY'), 'yyyymmdd') > asa_file_count.log)

daybefore=`TZ=aaa48 date +%d-%m-%Y`

if [[ $count -lt 20 ]]
then
echo "Alert - Source files are yet to be received for date: $daybefore" | mail -s "Alert : Source data files missing" s@g.com
fi
```

Comment: Kindly edit your post and format it properly...

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the ["how to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/) page for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.

Answer (score 2):

Parentheses are special to the shell.  Your SQL script contains parentheses you don't want the shell to process.  However, the shell processes all non-quoted parentheses.  Therefore, you can use quotes to prevent the parentheses in your SQL from being interpreted by the shell:

```
count=$(sqlplus $PROD_DB "@select count(*) from file_audit where (file_name like '%abc%' or file_name like '%dce%') and substr(file_name,17,8)=to_char(to_date(sysdate-2,'DD/MM/YY'), 'yyyymmdd')" > asa_file_count.log)
#                        ^ and similarly, a closing quote at the end, just before  ">asa_file..." .
```

Now, there is a second issue: you have

```
count=$(sqlplus ... > asa_file_count.log)
```

However, I think this means `count` will always be empty, since the count will go into `asa_file_count.log` and will not be available to be captured with `$()`.  I believe removing the `>asa_file_count.log` will probably do what you want:

```
count=$(sqlplus "$PROD_DB" "<your query>")
```

(I also put double-quotes around `$PROD_DB` just in case `PROD_DB`'s value contains any spaces.)

Comment: You capture the output of sqlplus. To compare it with a number, the output has to be the number and nothing else.
I doubt that. Usually at least a header is included. Thus you may have to do additional work, to get rid of all the rest, and in case of error ....